# Como ler apenas linhas especificas de arquivos .txt em C

Tags: c, arquivo

Olá, quero ler um arquivo `.txt` e buscar um nome específico nele.

Tenho o seguinte código que faz isso, porém verifica em todas as linhas do mesmo.

```js
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
 FILE *arq;
 char busca[80], nome[80], buscaIdade[80], buscaEnd[100];
 int tamanho, idade, endereco;

// Abre o arquivo
 arq = fopen("ex-1.txt", "r");

 if(arq == NULL) {
  printf("Erro na criacao do arquivo");
  exit(1);
 }

 printf("Digite um nome a ser buscado no arquivo: ");
 scanf("%[^\n]s", nome);

 strcat(nome, "\n");

 tamanho = strlen(nome);

    do {
        fgets(busca, tamanho+1, arq);

        if(strcmp(busca, nome) == 0) {
            fgets(buscaIdade, tamanho, arq);
            fgets(buscaEnd, tamanho, arq);

            printf("Nome: %s", busca);
            printf("Idade: %s", buscaIdade);
            printf("Endereco: %s\n", buscaEnd);
            exit(1);
        }
    } while(!feof(arq));

 printf("Pessoa nao cadastrada!");

// Fecha o arquivo
 fclose(arq);
}
```

Meu arquivo de `.txt` está estruturado linha por linha, ou seja:

linha1 - Nome;

linha2 - Idade;

linha3 - Endereço.

E assim por diante

Gostaria de saber como poderia estar fazendo para ler apenas essas linhas, múltiplas de 3 (contando a linha1 como 0) para quando for buscar um nome, buscar apenas nas linhas referentes a eles.

Grato. :D

---

### EDIT 1:

Pensei numa forma de fazer isso, ler apenas linhas específicas. E o que fiz foi contar as linhas do arquivo e quando o `nLinha` fosse equivalente a 0 ou um múltiplo de 3, eu leria e compararia suas informações:

```js
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
 FILE *arq;
 char busca[80], nome[80], buscaIdade[80], buscaEnd[100], c, letra = '\n';;
 int tamanho, idade, endereco, nLinhas = 0;

// Abre o arquivo
 arq = fopen("ex-1.txt", "r");

 if(arq == NULL) {
  printf("Erro na criacao do arquivo");
  exit(1);
 }

 printf("Digite um nome a ser buscado no arquivo: ");
 scanf("%[^\n]s", nome);

 strcat(nome, "\n");

 tamanho = strlen(nome);
    
    while(fread (&c, sizeof(char), 1, arq)) {
        if(c == letra) {
            nLinhas++;
        }
        
        if((nLinhas == 0) || (nLinhas % 3 == 0)) {
         fgets(busca, tamanho+1, arq);
            
            if(strcmp(busca, nome) == 0) {
 
             printf("Nome: %s", busca);
             printf("Idade: %s", busca);
             printf("Endereco: %s\n", busca);
             exit(1);
         }
  }
    }

 printf("Pessoa nao cadastrada!");
 
// Fecha o arquivo
 fclose(arq);
 
 return 0;
}
```

O problema que surge agora é que para comparar as informações, o `strcmp()` nunca vai retornar verdade porque o `fgets()` está ignorando a primeira letra dos textos.

Ex:

`ex-1.txt`

```html
qwe
1
asd
zxc
2
vbn
rty
1
fgh
```

E se eu printar o que tem em busca, me retorna:

```html
we

sd
xc

bn
ty

gh
Pessoa não cadastrada!
```

Comment: Como é um arquivo texto e portanto sequencial você não tem alternativa senão ir lendo linha a linha até encontrar o que procura. O que não entendi foi por qual razão você fica modificando a quantidade máxima de caracteres a serem lidos na função fgets a cada leitura, me parece que você interpretou errado o significado dos parâmetros da função.

Comment: Perdão é que estava tentando ler numa só linha e esqueci de alterar. Meu problema é que se eu digitar por exemplo 1 (uma idade existente), ele retornará ela e o resultado sairá confuso :v

Comment: Mas em questão a ler linha por linha, não teria alguma forma de verificar apenas em linhas específicas? Fala que altero na pergunta.

Comment: Se com "verificar apenas em linhas específicas" você quer dizer fazer a leitura de uma determinada linha sem ler as linhas anteriores então em um arquivo texto, isto é: sequencial, não dá. Se fosse um arquivo binário você poderia utilizar a função fseek para posicionar aonde será feita a próxima leitura.

Comment: só seria possível ler uma linha específica se **todas** as linhas do arquivo tiverem o mesmo tamanho, caso contrário você vai ter que fazer leitura sequencial

Comment: zentrunix eu tive uma ideia de como fazer e adicionei ao edit. O que me diz sobre? O que pode estar ocorrendo agora... :v

Answer (score 0):

Você deve usar arquivos em modo binário, eles possuem funcionamento similar, para criar/ler/gravar em arquivos binários você deve mudar os parâmetros de abertura da `fopen()`, como por exemplo `fopen("arquivo.txt", "rb");`. Usando arquivos em modo binário basta usar a função `fseek()`.